# Micronaut will not honor application.dev.yml when running in dev environment

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

When I run `gradle run` during development, shouldn't Micronaut be using an `application-dev.yml` if one exists? I've also tried compiling a jar and running it with:

```
java -jar build/libs/mockidm-0.5-all.jar -Dmicronaut.environments=dev
```

But Micronaut still only reads values from `application.yml`

Am I misunderstanding that `gradle run` runs the app in dev mode? If not, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
run {
  systemProperty('micronaut.environments','dev')
}
```

I couldn't seem to find this documented anywhere.

Comment: "I couldn't seem to find this documented anywhere." - It is mentioned in section 4.1 of our user guide at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.6/guide/index.html#environments which says "Additional active environments can be specified using the micronaut.environments system property or the MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS environment variable".

Comment: Agreed. That was not a dig at Micronaut's great documentation! I simply couldn't find it, and had done a fair amount of googling. I've found that just reading the entire user doc has enlightened me quite a bit. Thanks for the response!

Comment: "That was not a dig at Micronaut's great documentation" - I didn't take it as a dig.  You said you couldn't find it (not that you didn't think it was there) so I pointed to a place where it was.  I didn't think it was a dig.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the following environment variable

```
MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=dev
```

for running it locally